# Manipulate a default query doesn't work as expected in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to manipulate a default query on my **archive-event.php** page. What I want to query is to order events(my custom posts) by the closest event (based on it's date).
This is my code in **functions.php**:

```
function university_adjust_queries ($query) { 
if(!is_admin() && is_post_type_archive('event') && $query->is_main_query()) {
$today = date('Ymd');

$query->set('meta_key','event_date');
    $query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');
    $query->set('order','ASC');

$query->set('meta_query', array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'event_date',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value'   => $today,
            'type' => 'numeric'
        ),
    ),);

}
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','university_adjust_queries');
```

and this is my code in **archive-event.php** :

```
while ( have_posts() ) {

the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="event-summary">
            <a class="event-summary__date t-center" href="#">
                        <span class="event-summary__month">
                            <?php
                            try {
                                $event_Date = get_field( 'event_date' );
                                $event_Date = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $event_Date));
                                $eventDate = new DateTime($event_Date);
                            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                                echo 'error happened';
                            }
                         echo $eventDate->format( 'M' );
                            ?></span>
                <span class="event-summary__day"><?php
                  echo $eventDate->format('d');
                    ?></span>
            </a>

...
```

But the problem is even with different dates that my events have in my admin dashboard , **their dates are shown entirely wrong** (some are duplicates!)

This is the image of my archive-event page :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the type in your meta query to DATE?

```
$query->set('meta_query', array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'event_date',
            'compare' => '>=',
            'value'   => $today,
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    ),);
```